# Automation panel: what would cause a 135v input voltage?

Tags: ac, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, home-automation

I am building a home automation panel which is fed by 120v AC input mains power. The first connection in the panel is a GFCI breaker followed by 5v and 12v switched PSUs which power a relay board and arduino.

I recently noticed a few strange issues:

- Input AC voltage was reading 130-135v after warm up (~30 min of being on) when initially this value was 120v as expected
- 5v DC PSU drifts from ~4.9v-5.5v Over warm up period
- 12v DC PSU drifts from 11.9v to 13.5v+ over warm up period

2 questions:

- Is it possible a 135v AC line could force a PSU to significantly drift?
- What could be causing a 135v AC line internal And external to the panel?*

*Note: I still need to check other AC line voltages in my house to determine if this is an issue across one house breaker or rest of house. Have not had any Recent electrical issues in home.

[image]

Comment: _”Is it possible a 135v AC line could force a PSU to significantly drift?”_ Depends. What’s the input voltage rating? How are you measuring? If everything reads too high and you are using a normal battery powered multimeter, please check the battery. It’s unfortunately too common for them to read high when the battery is low.

Comment: No schematics, no information; anything could be happening. Check your AC voltage (and how it might change) without the panel connected because that would be the first step anyone would make when analysing the problem. You should make that step first before posting such an open-ended question.

Comment: @Andyaka- Thanks for the reply........simply asking for the schematic is another alternative vs. approaching my question with an entirely ignorant response. Schematic is attached if you have any interest in trying again.

Comment: I do appreciate good sarcasm when appropriate. Unfortunately, not here (usually). You might also be interested to know that it is good manners on this site to upvote answers that have helped you even if they haven't completely answered your question. Those that do should be formally accepted.

Comment: @sensei247, please read Andy's comment again. It is neither ignorant or rude. If you posted the original question without a schematic then the comment is justified. As it stands now we have no information about the power supplies so it's not clear how you expect an answer.

Comment: Check the battery in your multimeter. In many not-too-expensive multimeters, a battery close to flat will cause voltage readings to be higher than expected.

Comment: nice diagram ... the line voltage is unspecified

Answer (score 0):

Since there is absolutely no information about the PSU i have no clue why this might be happening! ...

1. If its a linear transformer based PSU then it can easily drift
   2.If it's an SMPS based PSU then they function from like 100V to 300V and drifting of output voltage is quite common... If you want precise output then i would suggest having a precise PSU or having a 7V psu and then passing it though linear regulator like 7805 .
   3.when it comes to measurement of the AC input i would suggest using a TRUE RMS volt meter .. since your SMPS PSU might be drawing an inconsistent current causing this issue.